# What options are available for storing application settings in asp.net mvc2?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-2, .net-4.0

I need to store the application settings somewhere, but can't find a satisfying solution. Read only settings are pretty easy to store in web.config, but what about settings for application administration that would should be accessible through web-page? Writing to web.config doesn't seem to be a good idea. I have considered storing the settings in custom xml file, but then if there is sensitive information involved in the settings, that seems to be problem, also if there are multiple users modifying the settings at the same time some kind of file locking has to be involved. Now I am inclined to store the app settings the MS-SQL database, it seems like a secure and well scale-able solution, however it feels wrong to have a table to store just one row - the setting. What's your opinion? How would you design that?

Are there any ready to go .NET solutions for storing dynamic web app settings?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your question is so subjective that I don't even know why I am answering it instead of voting to close. But anyway, a database is a good place. And if you are bored and tired of relational data there are great [NoSQL](http://nosql-database.org/) databases out there such as [MongoDB](http://www.mongodb.org/) and [RavenDB](http://ravendb.net/) that will make this very easy. And if you want a very fast database [Redis](http://redis.io/) could be worth checking out.

Storing things in files in a web application is far more difficult than it might look at the first place. If it is for readonly then web.config could indeed be a good place. But once you start writing you will have to take into account that a web application is a multithreaded environment where you will have to synchronize the access to this file. And what looked in the first place as an easy solution, could quickly turn into a nightmare if you want to design it properly. That's why I think that a database is a good solution as it gives you concurrency, security, atomicity, data integrity, ...

Answer (score 2):

I absolutely think that storing settings of dynamic nature in database is the right way. Don't feel bad about having one simple table. This table can save you a lot of headaches. If you'll code it smart you can really benefit from it (but that depends on the type of values you want to store). The only problem with db is that someone might actually modify values directly in database. But it can be easily solved. For example I have a "configuration-values" class that I feed from database upon start and put it to cache with some timeout. Then after a while I can lazily feed it again, catching situations like I mentioned above. I hope it makes some sense.